# Tools/Components for building a Survey Application

Tags: asp.net, survey, dynamic-pages

We are designing a survey application with the following features

1. The users will be able to select questions from a set of predefined questions.
2. Each question has a question type defined which dictates the type of answer (multiple choice, DB look up, free text etc)
3. The user can create a hierarchy of sections with multiple questions with in each section.
4. The responses of the survey will be stored to an SQL server database.

There is also a requirement to generate an output document from each survey response.

We are planning to implement this application using ASP.net.

I am looking for suggestions which will help us reduce the development effort. Is there any commercial/open source application which we can customize for our needs? is there any ready-made components which helps creation of dynamic ASP.net pages? I am only interested in application which i can host locally, as this has to be integrated to an existing application.

Comment: So what did you end up doing for your project? I was just assigned a survey application and need to figure out how I can make one that will pull questions out of the database and store answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be an exact fit, but worth looking at: [Surveymonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Unless feedback systems are your business's core competency, you'd be best off using a third-party system. Building a survey system is not as easy as it might seem, especially when it comes to reporting. Sure, you'll be able to bang out some simple reports without too much trouble, but every change wanted by a customer (or your boss) is time you'll be dumping into your survey and reporting engine when it could be spent on your actual business. Do yourself a favor and outsource that headache to a third party.

If your needs are simple, a freebie site like SurveyMonkey would be just fine. If you're looking for something more sophisticated, such as support for phone surveys, more advanced reporting, etc., you'd need to pay for a more advanced service, such as *(cough)* [the one I work for](http://www.mshare.net).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeplex.com/WebSurvey
looks like a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zodiac.NET Survey Engine](http://mentor-logic.com/products/zodiacnet/profile.aspx). It can be integrated direct in your ASP.NET website. No much work needed.

Answer (score 0):

[NSurvey](http://www.nsurvey.org/) used to exist for this, but I think they've gone solely commercial. If you can dig up the last open source release, it might be a good starting point.

Otherwise, don't build it. Subscribe to [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com)

Comment: I am in the same predicament. My boss said that we are going to build it. Our company relies solely on technology that we create, "we" feel that it is what separates us from our competition. It's very frustrating trying to find something free to help me because it doesn't do what I want. They are too simple and I need something better.

Comment: NSurvey lives on in http://survey.codeplex.com/ I think

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to have users use [InfoPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfoPath) or [Adobe Designer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Designer) to create the survey forms that are distributed to survey takers (either by e-mail or web-site).

With InfoPath, you can have the responses call back to Web Services that you have written. Or, with both the packages, you can have the responses e-mailed back to a particular address and the XML that is sent can be parsed and processed.